# Wordpress api post image raw data without being blank in media library

Tags: php, images, rest-api

So, to get to the heart of the matter, I want to post an image on a worpress site with the **api (v2)**.

First part of the problem is that I **don't have a url or file path**, I just have the **raw data of the image** in a variable that I get from an export done before.

The second part of the problem is that once posted (well normally), the image **appears blank** in the media library in the admin.

Here is my code :

```
if (isset($product['priority_web_image'])) {

            $image_name = $product['priority_web_image']['filename'];
            $data = $product['priority_web_image']['data'];
            $ext = substr($image_name, strpos($image_name, ".") + 1);
            if ($ext == 'jpg') {
                $ext = 'jpeg';
            }
            $mime_type = 'image/'.$ext;

            $headers = [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer '.$result_auth->access_token,
                "cache-control" => "no-cache",
                "Content-Type"  =>  $mime_type,
                "Content-Disposition" => "attachement;filename=".$image_name,
              ];

            $body = [
                "source_url"  =>  $data,
                "slug"        =>  "image_test_pimcore",
                "status"      =>  "future",
                "title"       =>  $image_name,
                "media_type"  => "image",
                "mime_type"   =>  $mime_type
            ];

            $options = [
                "headers"      =>  $headers,
                "form_params"  =>  $body,
                
            ];
            $result = $this->WPApi->request("POST", "media", $options);
            $bodyAry = json_decode($result->getBody());
            //echo print_r($bodyAry);
            return $bodyAry;
        }
```

I use Guzzle for make the request.

If anyone knows what I'm missing, I'll take it :-).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution !

```
      file_put_contents($filepath, base64_decode($data));

      // Make sure the image exist
      if (!file_exists($filepath)){return;}

      // Load the image
      $file = file_get_contents($filepath);

      // Get the filename
      $filename = $image_name? $image_name : basename($filepath);

      // Initiate curl.
      $ch = curl_init();
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url .'/wp-json/wp/v2/media/' );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1 );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $file );
      curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, [
          "Content-Disposition: form-data; filename=\"$filename\"",
          'Authorization: Bearer ' .$result_auth->access_token,
      ] );
      $result = curl_exec( $ch );
      curl_close( $ch );

      // Decode the response
      $api_response = json_decode($result);

      return $api_response;
```